# Call a Form Subroutine from a Module to modify a Form Control

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, forms

I'm having trouble working this around.
I have a form `MainForm`, with a ListBox control and a subroutine to add an Item to that ListBox:

```
Public Sub AddEntry(msg As String)
    EventLog.Items.Add(msg)
End Sub
```

In a separate module I have a Sub that does stuff and calls the `AddEntry` method in the form.

```
Module Routines
    Sub foo()
        My.Forms.MainForm.AddEntry(msg)
    End Sub
End Module
```

Here's what's happening:

- When `AddEntry` is called from a Sub within the form, it works all right.
- When `AddEntry` is called from the module, it just does nothing. No error, not anything.

*************** EDIT ***************
Ok, I got it working with Events as suggested. **Please let me know if this is a good way to do it.**

In MainForm:

```vb
Public Event AddEntryEv(txt as String)

'Event Handler
Private Sub AddEntry(txt As String) Handles Me.AddEntryEv
    EventLog.Items.Add(txt)
End Sub

'A public sub to be called from somewhere else that rises an event
Public Sub Log_AddEntry(txt As String)
    RaiseEvent AddEntryEv(txt)
End Sub

'To use routines in a module and call the Log_AddEntry method, I used a button click event:
Private Sub Btn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Btn.Click
    RoutineInModule(Me)
End Sub
```

And in a module I do something like this:

```
Module MainRoutines
    Sub RoutineInModule(ByRef Caller As MainForm)
        Caller.Log_AddEntry("THIS WILL APPEAR IN LISTBOX.")
End Sub
```

Comment: VB.NET forms are event driven, so you may find it better to use the event-driven system that is intended: [RaiseEvent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/raiseevent-statement).

Comment: You are referring to the default instance of the form in that code. Most likely it is not the default instance that you're looking at. That said, the real fault is the module referencing the form directly. That's bad design.

Comment: Thanks for the insight, I edited the original post, please let me know your thoughts.

Comment: No, that is very much not the way to do it. What's the point of the form raising an event only to handle it itself and then do what could have been done in the method that raised the event in the first place? If you were to use an event, the module should be raising it and the form handling it, so the module doesn't even have to know that the form exists. In this case though, a better option would like be to make your `Sub` a `Function` and have it return the data when called, then the for can add its own entry without the module knowing or caring what the data is for.

Comment: Also, there's no reason for that `Caller` parameter to be declared `ByRef` in that scenario.